# Bash IFS not splitting string correctly

Tags: bash, ifs

I am having trouble getting IFS to split the string correctly based on the colon delimiter. It seems that the `-e` inside the string is being considered as an option instead of being considered as a literal string.

```
#!/bin/bash
string_val="-e:SQA"

IFS=: read -a items <<< "$string_val"

echo "${items[0]}" # Prints empty value
echo "${items[1]}" # Prints SQA
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is being split correctly; the `-e` in `${items[0]}` is treated as an option to `echo`.

```
$ string_val="-e:SQA"
$ IFS=: read -a items <<< "$string_val"
$ printf '%s\n' "${items[0]}"
-e
```